# How to access range of bits in a bitset?

Tags: c++, bitset, std-bitset

I have a bitset which is very large, say, 10 billion bits.

What I'd like to do is write this to a file. However using `.to_string()` actually freezes my computer.

What I'd like to do is iterate over the bits and take 64 bits at a time, turn it into a `uint64` and then write it to a file.

However I'm not aware how to access different ranges of the bitset. How would I do that? I am new to c++ and wasn't sure how to access the underlying bitset::reference so please provide an example for an answer.

I tried using a pointer but did not get what I expected. Here's an example of what I'm trying so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bitset<50> bit_array(302332342342342323);
    cout<<bit_array << "\n";
    bitset<50>* p;
    p = &bit_array;
    p++;
    int some_int;
    memcpy(&some_int, p , 2);
    cout << &bit_array << "\n";
    cout << &p << "\n";
    cout << some_int << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

the output

```
10000110011010100111011101011011010101011010110011
0x7ffe8aa2b090                                                                                                                          
0x7ffe8aa2b098
17736
```

The last number seems to change on each run which is not what I expect.

Comment: `some_int` is uninitialized.  Then you copy two bytes to it, leaving the rest of it in its uninitialized state.

Comment: THere are bugs in your code, but regarding problem itself I cannot think about any solution but `test(pos)` each bit in position, pack 64bit into uint64_t and write this uint64_t into a file - manual, tedious and not nice

Comment: You might want to have a look at [bitset2](https://github.com/ClaasBontus/bitset2). It allows getting access to the underlying array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in the program. The maximum value `bitset<50>` can hold is `1125899906842623` and this is much less than what `bit_array` has been initialized with in the program.

`some_int` has to be defined as `unsigned long` and verify if `unsigned long` has 64 bits on your platform.

After this, test each bit of `bit_array` in a loop and then do the appropriate bitwise (OR and shift) operations and store the result into `some_int`.

```
std::size_t start_bit = 0;
std::size_t end_bit = 64;
for (std::size_t i = start_bit; i < end_bit; i++) {
    if (bit_array[i])
       some_int |= mask;
    mask <<= 1;
}
```

You can change the values of `start_bit` and `end_bit` appropriately as you navigate through the large bitset.

See [**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f593df00241d8597).

Comment: Sorry about the “errors”. I wrote the example using 50 because I was too lazy to write a really large bitset greater than 150 billion bits, but basically used 50 and an int to illustrate my problem of trying to get a range of bytes from a larger data size into a smaller data size (int) using bitsets. Essentially a solution to the example would solve my problem. That said I was hoping for a copy of 64 bits at a time because that made the most sense to me

Answer (score 0):

For accessing ranges of a `bitset`, you should look at the provided interface. The lack of something like <s>`bitset::data()`</s> indicates that you should **not** try to access the underlying data directly. Doing so, even if it had seemed to work, is fragile, hacky, and probably undefined behavior of some sort.

I see two possibilities for converting a massive `bitset` into more manageable pieces. A fairly straight-forward approach is to just go through bit-by-bit and collect these into an integer of some sort (or write them directly to a file as `'0'` or `'1'` if you're not that concerned about file size). Looks like P.W already provided code for this, so I'll skip an example for now.

The second possibility is to use bitwise operators and `to_ullong()`. The downside of this approach is that it nominally uses auxiliary storage space, specifically two additional bitsets the same size as your original. I say "nominally", though, because a compiler might be clever enough to optimize them away. Might. Maybe not. And you are dealing with sizes over a gigabyte each. Realistically, the bit-by-bit approach is probably the way to go, but I think this example is interesting at a theoretical level.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

constexpr size_t FULL_SIZE = 120; // Some large number
constexpr size_t CHUNK_SIZE = 64; // Currently the mask assumes 64. Otherwise, this code just
                                  // assumes CHUNK_SIZE is nonzero and at most the number of
                                  // bits in long long (which is at least 64).

int main()
{
    // Generate some large bitset. This is just test data, so don't read too much into this.
    bitset<FULL_SIZE> bit_array(302332342342342323);
    bit_array |= bit_array << (FULL_SIZE/2);
    cout << "Source: " << bit_array << "\n";

    // The mask avoids overflow in to_ullong().
    // The mask should be have exactly its CHUNK_SIZE low-order bits set.
    // As long as we're dealing with 64-bit chunks, there's a handy constant to handle this.
    constexpr bitset<FULL_SIZE> mask64(UINT64_MAX);
    cout << "Mask:   " << mask64 << "\n";

    // Extract chunks.
    const size_t num_chunks = (FULL_SIZE + CHUNK_SIZE - 1)/CHUNK_SIZE; // Round up.
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < num_chunks; ++i ) {
        // Extract the next CHUNK_SIZE bits, then convert to an integer.
        const bitset<FULL_SIZE> chunk_set{(bit_array >> (CHUNK_SIZE * i)) & mask64};
        unsigned long long chunk_val = chunk_set.to_ullong();
        // NOTE: as long as CHUNK_SIZE <= 64, chunk_val can be converted safely to the desired uint64_t.
        cout << "Chunk " << dec << i << ": 0x" << hex << setfill('0') << setw(16) << chunk_val << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Source: 010000110010000110011010100111011101011011010101011010110011010000110010000110011010100111011101011011010101011010110011
Mask:   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
Chunk 0: 0x343219a9dd6d56b3
Chunk 1: 0x0043219a9dd6d56b
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Shame that we can’t access the underlying bits because that seems like the most obvious thing to do here.